# Can they reach the point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]

According to the figure, pendulum $OA$ is released from position $A$ and it collides with another pendulum $OB$ at point $B$ and after the inelastic collision, they continue their oscillation. (Mass of each bob is $10\ gm$). Can they reach at point $C$ together, Explain with mathematical expression.
I have tried to solve it. I calculated the potential energy of the bob. From that, I have found the velocity of the bob at the time of hitting bob $B$. It is $0.9899\ m/s$.

If the collision was elastic I could calculate the new velocity. How can I solve this?

Then I want to calculate the Kinetic energy of the bobs at point $B$ and the potential energy at point $C$ by using $0.5\cdot (\text{mass of bob A+ mass of bob B})\cdot v^2$ and $(\text{mass of bob A+ mass of bob B})\cdot g\cdot h$.

If kinetic energy is $\ge$ potential energy, then it will be able to reach point $C$. Is it a correct procedure?

Am I going in the right way? Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke Conservation of Momentum (CoM) $p=mv$ here:

> For **any** collision occurring in an isolated system, momentum is
> conserved. The total amount of momentum of the collection of objects
> in the system is the same before the collision as after the collision.

First calculate the velocity of $m_1$ at $B$, using conservation of energy, as you did.

Then, since as kinetic energy is not conserved in an inelastic collision, use the CoM to calculate the velocity of $m_1+m_2$ immediately post-collision and then their associated kinetic energy. The latter will show they cannot reach the point $C$.

*Question for the OP:* what do you think happened to part of the kinetic energy of $m_1$ during the collision?

*Answer:* during this *inelastic* collision kinetic energy is not conserved. Part of the KE of $m_1$ is converted to work, work done to permanently deform either $m_1$, $m_2$ or both. Some KE may also be lost as sound energy ('thudding' noise) or heat (friction)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gert. Please check what I have done.
Given that,
m1= m2= 0.05 kg
h= 0.05 m
Potential energy at point A= Kinetic energy at point B
Or, m1*g*h= 0.5*m*v^2
Or, v= 0.9899 m/s

m1u1+m2u2= (m1+m2)V
Or, V= 0.49495 m/s

Their kinetic energy at point B= 0.5*(m1+m2)V^2 = 0.01225 J
Their potential energy at point C will be= (m1+m2)*g*h= 0.049 J which is less than the kinetic energy of point B.

So, they will not be able to reach point C.

Please let me know if everything is okay or not. Thank you again.

Comment: Yep, looks good to go.

Comment: Thank you @Gert

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.